# How to combine multiple condition expressions in .Net Core EF to filter data?

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using the below code to filter records based on dynamic column names

```
string[] colNames = {"firstName", "lastName", "Col3", "col4"}
string[] colValues = {"jac", "sam", "col3value","col4value"}

ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student), "t");
MemberExpression column = Expression.Property(param, colNames[0]);
ConstantExpression searchValue = Expression.Constant(colValues[0]);
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
Expression exp = Expression.Call(column, containsMethod, searchValue);
var deleg = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, bool>>(exp, param).Compile();

var students = context.StudentModel.Where(deleg).AsQueryable();
```

How do i do this for multiple columns (combining all the columns in array in my case)

Comment: What is the problem? `Expression.AndAlso` and `Expression.OrElse`. And please remove `Compile`, if you want to execute filter on the server side.

Comment: sorry, i am new to this, can you please point me to an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach, in this case, is to create many `Expression.Call` and combine these calls with `Expression.AndAlso` as was suggested by Svyatoslav Danyliv.

They must share the same parameter.

So the solution will be following:

```cs
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student), "s");
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

Expression combinedExpression = null; // this will be passed to context.StudentModel.Where

for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Length; i++)
{
    MemberExpression column = Expression.Property(param, colNames[i]);
    ConstantExpression searchValue = Expression.Constant(colValues[i]);

    Expression expression = Expression.Call(column, containsMethod, searchValue);

    combinedExpression = combinedExpression == null
        ? expression;
        : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpression, expression);
}
```

You don't need to compile `combinedExpression`, as `.Where` requests `Expression<Func<...>>`, not `Func` itself.

`var students = context.StudentModel.Where(combinedExpression);

To get all the filters to work correctly I assume you need to create separate expressions for different types e.g. `int`, `int?` to check them for equality as well (or >, => etc.). Because current `Contains` usage is very limited.

P.S. make sure you have correct **property** names in `colNames` array, otherwise you'll get an error at `Expression.Property` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student), "t");
Expression groupExp = null;

foreach (PageFilter filter in query.PageFilters)
{
                
    Expression con;
    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    con = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(param, filter.Name), containsMethod, Expression.Constant(filter.Value));
    groupExp = groupExp == null ? con : Expression.AndAlso(groupExp, con);

}

var deleg = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, bool>>(groupExp, param);

var students = context.StudentModel.Where(deleg).AsQueryable();
```

This worked for me.